# Convert red line in image to numpy list

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I want to measure the height difference to ground of the detected object in this pipe. The lower red line shall be the marker for minimum height. I thought I might first convert the lower red line into a numpy list but how would I do that? The red circles are drawn with `cv2.circle()` function.

[image]

**Edit:**

Thanks to ZdaR I am closer to solving my problem. This is his solution rewritten to work with python3:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def get_center(arr):
    return sum(arr)/len(arr)


def get_cluster_centers(arr, tolerance):
    clusters = [[arr[0]]]

    for ele in arr[1:]:
        if abs(clusters[-1][0] - ele) < tolerance:
            clusters[-1].append(ele)
        else:
            clusters.append([ele])

    clusters_centers = map(get_center, clusters)
    return clusters_centers


img = cv2.imread("/home/artur/Desktop/0.png")

# Segment the red color
mask = cv2.inRange(img, np.array([0, 0, 255]), np.array([0, 0, 255]))

for i in mask:
    print(i)

# Let's iterate the middle column and get the distance between the two red lines.
half_width = int(mask.shape[1]/2)
middle_column = mask[:, half_width]

idx = np.where(middle_column == 255)

# Since the width of line is not 1 px so we need to cluster the pixels to get a single center value.
centers = list(get_cluster_centers(idx[0], 5))

if len(centers) == 2:
    print("Distance between lines:", centers[1] - centers[0], "px")
```

It measures the pixel distance between upper and lower red line with the help of the middle column of the image. How would I iterate over all columns to determine the minimum distance between those two line or better, between detected object and lower red line? Do I get it right that this solution only takes the middle column into account?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert the red line into numpy list"? Do you want an array of (x,y) coordinates of all the pixels that lie on the circumference? Since you know the center and radius, and the equations defining circles are [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations), you can easily calculate them. | A lazy way to deal with it is just draw the circle (not as thick) into a black image, and [find all the non-zero pixels](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first segment the red color from the input image to get a binary mask then assuming that your red line is centered to the input image, we take the center column of that image and iterate over the column to find the red dot locations then simply find the distance in pixels as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def get_center(arr):
    return sum(arr)/len(arr)


def get_cluster_centers(arr, tolerance):
    clusters = [[arr[0]]]

    for ele in arr[1:]:
        if abs(clusters[-1][0] - ele) < tolerance:
            clusters[-1].append(ele)
        else:
            clusters.append([ele])

    clusters_centers = map(get_center, clusters)
    return clusters_centers


img = cv2.imread("/home/anmol/Downloads/HK3WM.png")

# Segment the red color
mask = cv2.inRange(img, np.array([0, 0, 255]), np.array([0, 0, 255]))

# Let's iterate the middle column and get the distance between the two red lines.
half_width = mask.shape[1]/2
middle_column = mask[:, half_width]

idx = np.where(middle_column == 255)

# Since the width of line is not 1 px so we need to cluster the pixels to get a single center value.
centers = get_cluster_centers(idx[0], 5)

if len(centers) == 2:
    print "Distance between lines:", centers[1] - centers[0], "px"
```

PS: I am kind on in hurry if this does not explain something feel free to ask in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check **Edit** section of my post.